# Does anyone has a flutter doc related to lenght.clamp property in flutter?

Tags: flutter, clamp

i want to read some document or medium.com examples about length.clamp(int,int) property on list view in flutter,

cause the function i am looking for is something to make this in listview flutter

layout is

[image]

as you can see, doing listvew.builder in flutter is okay for me i can put item count for home and about as 2 in itemcounts,
but the subcategory is not consistent, sometimes 2 items, 3 or even more.

any advise? i saw this post about clamp length but nothing else on medium or flutter docs to know more about it..

[Flutter show only less 6 length on list view builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66330437/flutter-show-only-less-6-length-on-list-view-builder)

im open for suggestion thanks

Comment: [num.clamp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/clamp.html)

Comment: thanks, do you think you can show me an example on how to implement it on my problem? i have been hardcoding a listview for a while now due to not knowing there is a solution like this. please help